# How do I pick the right cryptocurrency without becoming an expert in cryptocurrencies?

Tags: currencies

I live in a country where a certain national currency is used as legal tender. I do not understand how the local money works (e.g. how the national money supply is increased), nevertheless I can easily use it in my everyday life, for example to earn wages and pay for food. One factor that makes the local currency easy to use is that there is no alternative. In most circumstances I cannot pay with another currency.

Being interested in criptocurrencies, I'm faced with a difficult choice: Which currency do I want to use? Being an ignorant fool and unwilling to educate myself on how cryptocurrencies work—

**How do I choose a cryptocurrency to use (and support)?**

Answer (score 5):

As money, security is paramount. Bitcoin is still the safest and most proven crypto, despite what others claim. The network has the most miners, which makes attacking the network next to impossible.

Bitcoin does have a few drawbacks, but these are being fixed 1 by 1. Solutions like SegWit and Lightning Network are major advancements.

There’s nothing wrong with supporting Bitcoin as your first coin. Over time you can learn more and maybe get interested in other coins, but I find myself always going back to the original Bitcoin.

The fact that BTC was invented by an anonymous inventor and has no single leader, is also a major benefit.